# How to update progress view in customcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my app I have a uitableview with custom cell. 
Each cell has a button to select it and add a custom nsmanagedobject to an array.
I then iterate this array to download the selected file.

Downloading works, but I'm stuck with showing the progress on the cell progressview especially when the user scroll the tableview during download.

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CuctomCell

    let file = fileArray[indexPath.row] as! File
    cell.titleLabel.text = file.name

    if (file.isDownloaded != 0)
    {
        //File is downloaded and can be read
        cell.readLabel.hidden = false
        cell.readLabel.text = "READ"
        cell.selectBtn.hidden = true
        cell.fileLabel.hidden = true
        cell.progressView.hidden = true
        cell.fileLabel.text = file.filePath
        cell.fileLabel.hidden = false
        cell.openButton.hidden = false
    }
    else
    {
        //File is not downloaded show the select button to download
        cell.readLabel.hidden = true
    }

    if (self.selectedButtonsArray.containsObject(indexPath.row))
    {
        cell.selectBtn.selected = true
    }
    else
    {
        cell.selectBtn.selected = false
    }

    cell.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.selectBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.progressView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.selectBtn.addTarget(self, action: "downLoadFiles:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.openButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.openButton.addTarget(self, action: "openPDF:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

The action for adding the selected cell to a download array

```
@IBAction func downLoadFiles(sender: UIButton)
{
    let updateFile = self.fileArray.objectAtIndex(sender.tag) as! File

    if (downloadArray.containsObject(updateFile))
    {
        updateObjectIdentifierTag(updateFile, tag: sender.tag, action: "remove")
        downloadArray.removeObject(updateFile)
        selectedButtonsArray.removeObject(sender.tag)

        //print(downloadArray)
        sender.selected = false
    }
    else
    {
        updateObjectIdentifierTag(updateFile, tag: sender.tag, action: "add")
        downloadArray.addObject(updateFile)
        selectedButtonsArray.addObject(sender.tag)
        sender.selected = true
    }

    let addString = "ADD (\(downloadArray.count))"

    addButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: addString, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "updateCoreData")

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButton

}

func updateObjectIdentifierTag(mObject: File , tag: Int, action: String)
{
    let object = self.fileArray.objectAtIndex(tag) as! File

    if (action == "add")
    {
        object.tagIndex = tag
    }
    else if (action == "remove")
    {
        object.tagIndex = -1
        object.taskIdentifier = -1
    }

    do
    {
        try context.save()
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Unable to save")
    }

}
```

I've created an array of nsdictionary for the download, added a key for indexPath.

Tried this code

```
   func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"ident == %d", downloadTask.taskIdentifier)
    let arr = self.selestedIndexPaths.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        let indexpath = arr[0]["indexPath"] as! NSIndexPath
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexpath) as! CuctomCell
        cell.progressView.hidden = false
        let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        cell.progressView.progress = progress
        print("IndexPath: \(indexpath)")

        })
}
```

but i get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when the cell is not visible.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: so what's the problem? You say you're stuck but you don't mention on what.

Comment: @rocky i'm stuck at the function: didwritedata , where i should show a progress view in each cell that is downloading, how can I implement the logic in this function to show the cell that is currently downloading even when the cell is not visible?